# ImmutableJS List type not defined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, immutable.js

I'm getting the Typescript error:

```
'List' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

But the immutable.d.ts does have the export interface List type. So I'm unsure of what is going on.

Here is the file I'm trying to reference it from:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {IProduct} from "./Product";
const { List } = require('immutable');

interface GantryFootProps {
    orders: List<IOrder>;
}

export interface IOrder {
    product: IProduct
    quantity: number;
}

export const GantryFoot: React.FunctionComponent<GantryFootProps> = (props) => {
    return (<div>
        <h2>Gantry Foot</h2>
    </div>)
}
```

my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and my webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader','sass-loader'],
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    externals: {
        "react": 'React'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'main.css',
        chunkFilename: '[name].css'
    })]
};
```

Any other clues as to the reason for the error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is your file extension `.tsx` ?

Comment: @AkashDathan yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running TypeScript 3.8+ you can use `import type { List } from "immutable"`([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQA9A3KJLHAN4CSACsQCYBXfAF84REnABEAOgZ8IQ-FPqto8GAE8wWTnAAywVPDETSZUCEExkAIwA2WWnTrAAdjCxQCeXQHFkDyhNADEICBgFMHQOOjh4uGh+L1QALgMjGAAeLgB5KGSoAD56ERd3T29fOF4BYXgOMrosAA82eAqvH1xdPIKvTjiEsDr8dNrFeqH4gEdBQJhgLXS3QRBbL1KXVva4XAg3YzgAoNDwmHTsPBgZEME3fGADgGESSDcsDyyTmGCwiKiqCKcAAvHAABQjCDRACUoOBsQScEoMEEUDcEKy-GAADcitMkXAsgALABMRR+wTg-2yDDJ+KRWQY2LxMLoIiAA)),

for lower TypeScript versions you can use `import { List } from "immutable"`([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQA9A3KJLHAN4CSACsQCYBXfAF84REnABEAOgZ8IQ-FPqto8DnAAywVPDETSZUCEExkAIwA2WWnTrAAdjCxQCeLHADiyZ1ACeAGIQEDAKYOgcdHAxcND8rqgAXNq6MAA8XADyUAlQAHz0IvZOLm4ecLwCwhrFdFgAHmzwpa7uuJ7Zua6c0bFg1fgpVYo1fTEAjoK+MMAw-imOgiAWrkX2jc1wuBCOet4zAcGhKdh4MDKBgo74wLsAwiSQjljO6T5+QSFhxBH5cABeOAACgGEAiAEpAf8orE4JQYIIoI4Qel+MAAG75cZwuDpAAWACZ8h8YAE4McMgwidi4ekGOisRC6CIgA)) and have webpack remove immutable from your chunk.

[Documentation for `import type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-exports)

Comment: In this case I'm getting 'module immutable cannot be found'.